# Reversing a sequence using recursion

Tags: python

the following code does not work. But the logic seems correct to me.

```
def reverse1(seq):
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    else:
        return (seq[-1],) + reverse(seq[:-2])
```

Comment: `reverse1(seq[:-1])`

Comment: Sequence is a tuple, right?

Comment: `if len(seq) <=1: return seq`

Answer (score 0):

Just change a number and the name of the function called recursively and it fixes it

```
def reverse1(seq):
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    else:
        return (seq[-1],) + reverse1(seq[:-1]) # <--- Here
```

Answer (score 0):

smac89 is right, 
try this

```
return (seq[-1],) + reverse1(seq[:-1])
```

And I think this image will help you.

[image]